# Just found out my ex employer didn't pay out my vacation pay

Tags: vacation

I was a working student a couple of months ago at a company. We had an informal agreement when it came to vacation that I can just not work if I don't have the time to, and that's my vacation. But obviously I didn't get paid for those days/weeks as I didn't work. At the time I thought that was entirely reasonable.

However, I just found out that there is legislation where I live that I am entitled to a minimum amount of **paid** vacation even as a working student. I haven't received any of that, I only received the payments for my hours worked. Thus I am literally owed a certain amount of money by that company.

Note that while I did have a written contract with that company, it doesn't mention anything about vacation pay. It does however mention that I am not entitled to "extra payment", which I believe is against the law if it is meant to exclude vacation pay.

My question is how should I proceed? Do I just politely contact HR about this? How likely are my chances that they will fix this without escalating it?

Please don't debate legislation here, take it as a given. Hence location is irrelevant. I just want to know how to approach the company regarding this.

Comment: When you didn't work did you simply not show up or not do any work on those dates or did you have to formally request to not do work on specific dates?

Comment: sf02 I simply wouldn't show up and they would know beforehand by way of me not creating an entry/entries in our team calendar for that week/day.

Comment: Please specify the country because the procedure may depend on it.

Comment: We're you a casual employee, or part time employee?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I don't know what you mean by casual employee, but as a working student I was a part time employee.

Comment: @csstudent1418 Before proceeding, you should find out what I mean.

Comment: Even if some working students may be able to claim paid vacation, this does not necessarily apply to all contracts, or not in the same way. Location **is** important to determine if you are actually owed anything, as well as your exact status. If you were paid for hours worked rather than a fixed amount per week/month (with a fixed amount of hours for the same period), you may not be owed anything, or not the same amount -- this will vary per location

Comment: NB: The **legislature** is the body of (usually) elected people which make laws (e.g. Parliament, Congress, House of Commons, etc.). They produce **legislation**, which are the laws which state what people are required to do or forbidden from doing.

Comment: Between school and university I worked in Germany for a company with a very famous US parent. Worked for three months, and pay was good. Two weeks later I received a letter. First, they found I hadn't taken my six days of holidays, so they paid for that. Second, because I hadn't taken the holidays, the classified it as overtime, so they added another 50%. Nine days pay, almost half a month. Unfortunately you didn't give a "country" tag.

Comment: "Hence location is irrelevant." Location is highly relevant. For example, based on what you wrote, if you were in my city and state, you would be out of luck. The laws here are very specific about both accumulation and USE of paid time off. And if you're in the US, city and state might both affect the answer. As an example, in my state, based on what you wrote, the employer was within their rights to withhold unused paid time off. In another state, that might not be true.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you've finished there I'd approach this by reaching out to their HR (or whoever handled payroll) and suggest that there appears to have been a mistake with your last payment as your holiday pay hasn't been included. Be calm, be genial, you'd be surprised how much people will sometimes bend over backwards to help resolve your issue simply because you *didn't* go in guns blazing. *Especially* where the issue you're bringing to them could get them in all kinds of trouble were it to escalate, and since this would have the potential to go legal and no-one wants to be the reason why their employer gets a drubbing in court I'd say this qualifies.

The advantages of this are:

1. You're presenting your entitlement to the pay as a *fait accompli* - you aren't asking *if* you're entitled to it. If this is ignorance or confusion rather than malice then being the confident party on your position and entitlements from the very outset only benefits you.
2. You're giving them a graceful "out" - if they were knowingly trying to pull a fast one they can cover by saying "whoops.. sorry about that it should have been included". And if they *weren't* then by not going in accusing them of this you avoid any overly-defensive reaction.

If they try and argue the toss and suggest you aren't entitled to it then stay calm, stay reasonable, and gently point out that under legislation X you'll have accrued Y  holiday entitlement during your time there. Add that you've checked you records and you've definitely only been paid for the hours you actually worked (otherwise they'll ask you to go do this and you'll have to go through the whole conversation again later).

If they're *still* not for shifting then you need to get outside help - that could be a local governmental labour department or a lawyer, no way to know without more info on location.